# Query Distinct/Unique Value Counts for All Tables in a database - MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Is there a way to query the table name, column name, and distinct value count **per column** **for all tables in a Database**? How can I do this?

I'm on SQL Server Management Studio (2018)

I need to get a resulting table like this

```
TableName ColumnName Distinct Values 

table1         col1        10

table1         col2        9

table1         col3        20

table2         col1        10

table2         col2        9

...            ...         ...
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *!I'm on SQL Server Management Studio (2018)"* but what version of SQL Server are you using? SSMS  2018 supports SQL Server 2008-2019.

Comment: Also, yes, you *could* do this with dynamic sql but it will be **very** slow; `DISTINCT` is not a cheap operator and doing it on **every** column in **every** table is going to be *very* expensive. Why do you *want* to do this? Smells like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Though, if you're using SQL Server 20189 then you could use [`APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/approx-count-distinct-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), which is less expensive that `COUNT(DISTINCT )`, however, as the name says, it's an approximation.

Comment: @Larnu Data migration project. Moving stuff onto a datawarehouse and I need to confirm if the data was preserved, specifically through distinct value counts. Cost / Resource is not much of an issue. Just need to get these counts.

Comment: I would suggest there are better ways of validating than that.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2012 @Larnu

Comment: @Larnu I believe there would be, though I don't really have a choice for this one. Just need to get it done :(

Comment: Join `sys.tables` and `sys.columns` and generate a very long SQL, that you can execute. Of course, you can split it into smaller chinks (by table, for example). But as of the goal of your task `count(distinct(column))` to validate data worth nothing and looks like 'I just do what I was told'.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an efficient way to query the table name, column name, and distinct value count per column for all tables in a Database?

TL;DR: **No**, there is not an efficient way.

---

To be able to do this, you're going to need to use dynamic SQL and then (a hell of) a lot of `COUNT(DISTINCT {Column})` aggregate functions. Adding the `DISTINCT` operator to a `COUNT` makes the function *far* more expensive. This can easily slow down a simple query with only one  `COUNT(DISTINCT {Column})`, however, you want to do this on **EVERY** column in **EVERY** table in your database (that can be effected by a  `COUNT(DISTINCT {Column})`).

There is no way to make that efficient, it will instead be incredibly slow, and I would not be surprised if it takes hours, or days, to run with a large enough database and could easily suffer from being a deadlock victim.

Personally, I would rethink what ever it is you are trying to achieve with this requirement.

Comment: I guess a better phrase would be "is there a way" and "how". I rephrased my ask to keep things clearer for whoever.

 I get your point, but unfortunately, the sample result/table in my description is what I am tasked to obtain, and nothing else. Thanks though, I appreciate the input and agree on your points.